use the mcmId from the managed configurations Iframe
I am trying out with android management API and when trying the managed configurations i found that google provides the iframe which returns the name and the mcmId. The docs say that i need to put the mdmId in the managed configurations template. So I made the managed configurations template like below.
{
  "templateId": "Id",
  "configurationVariables": {
    mcmId: "mcmId received from the iframe"
  }
}

the policy did not cause any error or issue. The policy patch was successfull.
But the applied managedconfigurations does not work. is it the proper way to apply the mcmId to managed Configurations template?
Any help is much obliged

Per the documentation, the templateId is the ID of the managed configurations template. This is the ID you receive from the iFrame once you created a managed configuration profile. The configurationVariables on the other hand is an optional field  which is a map containing <key, value> configuration variables defined for the configuration.
When submitting the information, the values provided are stored and sent to the device.  There is no validation from the server that the templateId provided exists, or that the values in the configurationVariables are required/valid.
Sample code below shows how you can apply the managed configuration profile created on the iFrame to the device:
"managedConfigurationTemplate": {
      "templateId": "id_received_from_the_iframe",
      "configurationVariables": {
             "%username%": "..."
      }
    }


"templateId": "mcmId received from the iframe"

it does not work I tried on F5 Access. I creted a VPN profile using the iframe and assigned the mcmId from the iframe as you suggested but the thing i configured didn't work
